# Problem with inserting a new row - unknown column name reported missing

Tags: insert

I'm new to SQL Anywhere. I have a SQL Anywhere 11 database that was not designed by me. I'm trying to insert a new row in a table with let's say 3 columns. When I execute the sql statement

```
insert into table (Col, Col2, Col3)
values('1','2','3')
```

I get a message:

> Column 'ColX' not found
> Error code=-143, SQL state=42S22

There is no such ColX. I tried to search in the triggers, but they are too many. With other tables I do not have that problem.

Comment: If you can't search in your triggers, how do you expect the internet people do that for you? Since you didn't provide the actual table definition or the actual statement that fails, nor the error message, it's unlikely anyone can help.

Comment: No, I'm not expecting anyone to do my job, but I expect anyone to suggest an idea, like some others, who suggested to use SET TEMPORARY OPTION FIRE_TRIGGERS = OFF, which perfectly suits me.